# How can I increase the size of a checkbox inside of a table?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, html-table, resize

I'm trying to enlarge the checkboxes I've placed inside of a table.  `width:###px; height:###px;` only seem capable of decreasing the size.  If they are set to anything higher than the default size, the checkboxes simply remain default while the div gets as large as I specified.  I have tried setting padding to zero to no avail.

Here is an example of my table body code:

```
%tbody
    -for foo in @foos
        %tr{:class=> cycle("even","odd")}
            %td{:style => "text-align:right;"}= foo.name
            -for bar in @bars
                %td
                    %input{:name =>"checkboxname", :type=> "checkbox", :checked => true, :style => "display:block;margin: 0 auto;width:20px;height:20px;padding:0px"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the regular checkboxes aren't really customizable, you might be interested in using a different approach.

http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css

Comment: Thanks! I was just starting to think I'd have to make my own checkboxes, and it looks like this may be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's not really a great way to do this cross-browser.
[This page](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/checkbox/) shows some good details about it

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that.  Thank you.

Comment: Of course you could always make your own from scratch, or use custom images for checkboxes and program them to change onclick, but that's a pain... not really a lot of choices though.